# App standby behavior and alarms

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I looked into the documentation but it isn't clearly mentioned. When an app is in standby mode, is it able to receive a wake-up from the alarm manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do u define by a wakeup?

A. Showing a certain activity - yes.

B. Showing a notification - yes.

C. More option? - yes.

Basiclly - yes. You can do it, it depends on the way you set your receivers.

Comment: Usually I start an intent service.

Comment: And what do u do with? That is the question. What would u like to do?

Comment: This shouldnt be a problem. AlarmManager should do the trick. Dont forget to reload the data from the local db when the app returns from standby.

Comment: What do you mean by "realod data from the local db"? It's not clear.

Comment: A. You are downloading data for the app when the alarm is set.
B. Your app is in standby.
C. Need to save the data, i guess a db on the device or something like that.
D. when the user reopens the app it needs to reload the data so it will be with the updated data.

Comment: Ok, but it should the "normal" path, download->save->reaload when user open the app. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes. agree. that is what i ment.

Comment: Think about SyncAdapter maybe